# Cannot deploy mongodb StatefulSet with volumes for replicas grater than one

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

### Context

I'm sharing `/data/db` directory, which is mounted as a Network File System volume among all pods controlled by StatefulSet.

### Problem

When I set `replicas: 1` stateful set correctly deploys mongodb. Problem starts when I scale up (nr. of replicas grater than one e.g. `replicas: 2`)
All consecutive pods have `CrashLoopBackOff` status.

### Question

I understand error message -check debug section below. But, I don't get it. Basically, what I try to achieve is stateful deployment of mongodb, so even
after pods are deleted they will persist data. Somehow, mongo stops me from doing that because `Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db director`.
My questions are: What am I doing wrong? How can I deploy mongodb so it's stateful and persist data, while scaling up stateful set?

### Debug

**Cluster state**

```sh
$ kubectl get svc,sts,po,pv,pvc --output=wide
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE   SELECTOR
service/mongo   ClusterIP   None         <none>        27017/TCP   10h   run=mongo

NAME                     READY   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES
statefulset.apps/mongo   1/2     8m50s   mongo        mongo:4.2.0-bionic

NAME          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE     IP          NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/mongo-0   1/1     Running            0          8m50s   10.44.0.2   web01       <none>           <none>
pod/mongo-1   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m48s   10.36.0.3   compute01   <none>           <none>

NAME                                CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                     STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolume/phenex-nfs-mongo   1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    phenex-nfs-mongo                           22m   Filesystem

NAME                                     STATUS   VOLUME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolumeclaim/phenex-nfs-mongo   Bound    phenex-nfs-mongo   1Gi        RWX                           22m   Filesystem
```

**Log**

```sh
$ kubectl logs -f mongo-1
2019-08-14T23:52:30.632+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=mongo-1
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.0
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-08-14T23:52:30.635+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0" }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" } }
2019-08-14T23:52:30.642+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
2019-08-14T23:52:30.643+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-08-14T23:52:30.643+0000 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-08-14T23:52:30.643+0000 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2019-08-14T23:52:30.643+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-08-14T23:52:30.643+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

**Error**

```sh
Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable). 
Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
```

**YAML** files

```
# StatefulSet
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: mongo
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: mongo
        tier: backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:4.2.0-bionic
          command:
            - mongod
          args:
            - "--replSet=rs0"
            - "--bind_ip=0.0.0.0"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: phenex-nfs-mongo
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
      - name: phenex-nfs-mongo
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: phenex-nfs-mongo

# PersistentVolume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: phenex-nfs-mongo
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  nfs:
    server: master
    path: /nfs/data/phenex/production/permastore/mongo
  claimRef:
    name: phenex-nfs-mongo
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain

# PersistentVolumeClaim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: phenex-nfs-mongo
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

Answer (score 3):

## Problem:

You are deploying more than one pod using the same pvc and pv.

## Solution:

Use `volumeClaimTemplates`, [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components)

## Example:

```
# StatefulSet
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: mongo
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: mongo
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: mongo
        tier: backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:4.2.0-bionic
          command:
            - mongod
          args:
            - "--replSet=rs0"
            - "--bind_ip=0.0.0.0"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: phenex-nfs-mongo
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: phenex-nfs-mongo
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 100Mi
```

Comment: `You are deploying more than one pod using the same pvc and pv.` Don't get me wrong. But this is exactly what I want to achieve. I want to share db director among all pods, so all pods in `Stateful Set` will have the same content -thus, my pods will be stateful. Why is that a problem? It is the same use case as, if I was sharing `index.html` among all pods with nginx deployment. Much oblige for explanation :)

Comment: You cannot achieve that with MongoDB, because if you mount one pv for multiple pod it must be read-only and MongoDB need write access to storage.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But, I specify write access for my nodes by setting `accessModes` option to `ReadWriteMany` on pv and pvc. So theoretical I should be able to read and write to shared volume.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but MongoDB is creating a few files in `/data/db` directory and is able to find out that another instance is already using the same storage

Comment: Can you point me towards resources that shows how to correctly deploy mongo as stateful set with persistent data? Thanks!

Comment: My example should be sufficient for start, you can also look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/)